# Passport Components not showing up in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I followed this [tutorial](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport) and I'm on "**Passport's default Vue frontend**". The problem now is the *Vue Components* **not** showing up in *Laravel* **5.3**.

The *resources/js/**app.js***:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
reuire('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);
Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);
Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

The *resources/views/**home.blade.php***:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <passport-clients></passport-clients>
        <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
        <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: require vs reuire?

Answer (score 2):

Run "npm install" and gulp. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you calling your app.js within your layout? i.e.

**layouts/app.blade.php**

```
  <script src="{{ elixir('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```